# How to lower the minimum volume? (Nougat 7.1.2 through LineageOS 14.1)

Tags: lineageos, volume-control, xposed-framework

The minimum volume level available for alarm and ring settings is visually twice as much on the control in the settings as what is available for media and is just way too loud.

I am not looking to add more steps between the available volume levels; just to lower the minimum for alarm and ring.

Phone is rooted and has xposed as well, though I didn't find a relevant module. Strong preference for an open-source solution, as I won't be installing some random app with excessive permissions.